# exception when trying to upload a file

Tags: java, azure, sdk, quarkus

I am trying to upload a file to Azure Blob Storage but I am getting an error when I push the file into the storage.

I am using java 11 with Quarkus for development.
On the POM I have added the artifact  azure-storage-blob and azure-sdk-bom

Code:

```
BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClientBuilder()
                .endpoint("...")
                .sasToken("...")
                .containerName("random-files")
                .blobName("file")
                .buildClient();

String randomText = "random string";
blobClient.upload(BinaryData.fromString(randomText));
```

**Resume error**

> io.net.cha.DefaultChannelPipeline] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion

**Full error log:**

> WARN  [io.net.cha.DefaultChannelPipeline] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion
> at io.vertx.core.http.impl.VertxHttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(VertxHttpRequestDecoder.java:35)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpObjectDecoder.decode(HttpObjectDecoder.java:273)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:404)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:371)
> at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248)
> at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901)
> at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:818)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
> at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
> at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
> at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Do you have any idea what is the problem? I am just using the basics for upload a file using Quarkus but looks like there is a problem of versions or something like that.

Comment: Can you add your pom.xml? Looks like you are missing some base netty packages?

Comment: I dont  think so.. actually I added the dependency
 <dependency>
      <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
      <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
      <version>5.0.0.Alpha2</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency> to add all missing dependencies

Comment: why scope provided? that would indicate the runtime provides the lib

Answer (score 0):

The error messages shows that ssl issue.

Please refer the [link](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/azure-storage-blob-component.html) for usage and configuration details

The **Azure Storage Blob Service component**, URI syntax: `azure-storage-blob:accountName/containerName`

**MAVEN COORDINATES**

[Create a new project with this extension on code.quarkus.io](https://code.quarkus.io/?extension-search=camel-quarkus-azure-storage-blob)

Or add the coordinates to your existing project:

```
< dependency>
    < groupId>`org.apache.camel.quarkus`< /groupId>
    < artifactId>`camel-quarkus-azure-storage-blob`< /artifactId>
< /dependency>
```

Check the [User guide](https://camel.apache.org/camel-quarkus/next/user-guide/index.html) for more information about writing Camel Quarkus applications.

**SSL IN NATIVE MODE**

This extension auto-enables SSL support in native mode. Hence you do not need to add `quarkus.ssl.native=true` to your `application.properties`.

Refer  [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl)

If still you are facing the issue please raise a issue here [here](https://github.com/apache/camel-quarkus/issues)